# Blocking Queue Vs Classical implementation of Producer Consumer pattern

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns

I got to know that we can use `BlockingQueue` instead of classical `wait()` and `notify()` while implementing the Producer Consumer pattern. My question is, which implementation is more efficient? In an article about blocking queues it's been written that- "you don't require to use `wait` and `notify` to communicate between Producer and Consumer"

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/02/producer-consumer-design-pattern-with.html#ixzz2lczIZ3Mo" . Does this simplicity come at the cost of efficiency??

Comment: I would worry more about readability and maintenance. How much time will you save future developers by using a simple data structure? On the flip side, if you roll your own solution, how much time will they waste trying to figure out why you didn't just use a BlockingQueue?

Comment: Never thought of it :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the number of objects produced/consumed every second is less than 100000, then you'll be unable to see the difference for standard or your own implementations.

Otherwise, you have following options to speed up your code:

- use ArrayBlockingQueue instead of LinkedBlockingQueue: no need to create wrapper object for each transferred message. Another advantage of ArrayBlockingQueue is that producer thread is blocked if the queue is full - and indeed, producer should slow down if consumer is not fast, otherwise, we will end up with memory exhausted.
- send messages in batches, say in arrays of 10 messages each. This reduces the contention of threads on shared object.

If you have to send tens of millions messages per second, look at [Lmax Disruptor](http://lmax-exchange.github.io/disruptor/).

Comment: May I know why it's 100000 which makes difference?

Comment: This could be 1000000, depending on a concrete machine. For low-level machines, implementation of quick synchronized algorithm takes about 1 mks. So 100000 events per second does not cause contention.

Answer (score 4):

The BlockingQueue will be faster, because it does **not** use wait/notify or synchronized for the queue access. All concurrent packages implement the lock-free algorithms using the Atomic-classes.

Think about a queue of 100 elements, and 1000 Threads wanting to do their work. With a synchronized implementation, for each element 999 Threads need to wait, till 1 Thread has picked it's task. With a lock-free algorithm, 100 Threads **simultaneously** pick their task, and only the other 900 have to wait.

Comment: But 900 threads will still be waiting right?. So, there must be mechanism of notigying(notify()) the waiting (wait()) threads... It still looks like a wait-notify combination to me.

Comment: Correct, but not for the actual access. Edit incoming.

Answer (score 2):

BlockingQueue is simply a class that puts wait() and notify() to this common use. Generally, doing it yourself is just reinventing the wheel, and only worth it if you have lots of producers and consumers and you can optimize in some way that's specific to your code.

Comment: ya.. I understand the - "reinventing the wheel" part. If i have only one producer and one consumer, which one will be faster Blocking Queue or the classical one?

Comment: Technically, the "classical" way creates one fewer Object, and there may be other slight differences in however you implement it, but again, it's negligible and not worth the additional effort and possibility of bugs.